# Double integration with $e^{-x^2}$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, measurable-functions, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I am learning Fubini right now and I want to integrate
$$
\int_U e^{-x^2}y d\lambda_2 ,
$$
whereby
$$
U=\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: 0 \leq y \leq 1, \quad y^{2} \leq x \leq 1\right\}
$$

But as you may already see, we cannot do this without using the error function so I thought that one can maybe use polar coordinates and then apply fubini but I dont know how the set $U$ changes and what the new limits are.

Comment: Can I ask, what is $\lambda_2?$

Comment: @apkg 2 dimensional lebesgue measure

Comment: you dont need the error function, just use Fubini theorem

Comment: @Masacroso but if I integrate over y then I have $1/2 e^{-x^2}$ and then? How to integrate?

Comment: The order of integration could be reversed by rewriting the defining condition for elements of $U$ as $0 \le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le \sqrt{x}$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang thank you thats what i meant

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Geoffrey Trang I got

$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{x}} e^{-x^2}y dy dx = \int_0^1  \frac{xe^{-x^2}}{2}dx = (e-1)/4e
$$